# Cant see deploy to server option in Eclipse

Tags: force.com, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Neon vs.
And I have Installed force.com IdE.
When I create project I dont see Deploy to server option on it.
Is anybody facing same issue?

Comment: is your is works as online/offline ?

Comment: I have made it online